# Not Finding GKE MultidimPodAutoscaler in 1.20.8-gke.900 Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

When trying to test out a **MultidimPodAutoscaler** in a GKE Cluster running **1.20.8-gke.900**:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: MultidimPodAutoscaler
...
```

I get the following helm error:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "MultidimPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling.gke.io/v1beta1"

Looking into it further:

```
kubectl explain MultidimPodAutoscaler
```

Basically confirms it doesn't seem to exist:

> the server doesn't have a resource type "MultidimPodAutoscaler"

and running:

```
kubectl api-versions
```

Does not even list **autoscaling.gke.io/v1beta1** as an available API.

From my understanding, GKE added **MultidimPodAutoscaler** in **1.19.4-gke.1700** so I was expecting it to be available.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multidimensional-pod-autoscaling

Any help understanding what I am missing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Vertical Pod Autoscaling for your cluster.
You can enable it via the UI or you can update your cluster with the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER_NAME \
    --enable-vertical-pod-autoscaling
```